# Javascript Error - addPreSearch is not a function - Dynamics CRM

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm, crm, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-365

I am trying to filter the lookup based on some conditions and hence using **addPreSearch**. I am using the following code,

```
function filterLookup() {
    debugger;
  try {

    var conditionalattribute= Xrm.Page.getAttribute("vrp_conditionalattribute").getValue();

    if (conditionalattribute!= null && conditionalattribute!= undefined)
    {
        Xrm.Page.getAttribute("filteredattribute").addPreSearch(function () {
            addLookupFiler();
        });
    }
}
catch (e) {
    console.log(e.Message);
}
```

}

But I am getting below error on **addPreSearch** line

[image]

Please note that I am using CRM v8.2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you do not get presearch on attribute but rather it's control

```
formContext.getControl(arg).addPreSearch(myFunction)
```

[Commnutiy forum for reference](https://community.dynamics.com/crm/f/microsoft-dynamics-crm-forum/287007/xrm-page-getcontrol-addpresearch-is-there-a-bug-with-crm-2016?pifragment-97030=1)